# Let users upload one more post on a certain condition (kotlin list count)

Tags: android, kotlin

I only allow users to upload 2 posts. before uploading a new post I check that if `uploadedPost.count() < 2` then only let them upload a new one.

but now I'm trying that if

```
uploadedPost.forEach { 
   it.status == "Live" 
}
```

if any of the posts within uploadedPostList has a LIVE status, minus 1 from uploadedPost.count() like make a room for one more post. Trying forEach reduces the count by 1 but If I have two Live posts it still reduces it by 1 though the final result I'm expecting should be 0 (2 max post - 2 Live Posts).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to simplify your logic you could only add uploadedPost++ if status = final then I think your logic will be simpler.

Comment: Please checkout the code snippet I just posted down.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the relevant code? If it's just what you've posted, I don't see any subtraction happening at all.

```
countedPost = uploadedPost.count()

uploadedPost.forEach { 
    if( it.status == "Live"){
        countedPost--} 
    }
}    
if (countedPost < 2){
    
Post more
}
```

You really shouldn't be adding Posts that don't count anyway, unless you really need to track that for another reason.

Comment: You can see the code snippet here -> https://gist.github.com/kasem-sm/da680f28cba046bc845bf0816b8c4a57

Comment: Does the IF execute twice when the ForEach on the list is run on a user with 2 posts? I don't develop for android im just trying to help lol

Comment: that's what I wanted to know. If it doesn't executes twice, I want it to & if it does why the code isn't working :(

Comment: There's no way to log/print something, change some other variable so that you can see if it executes twice? At least then you know what the problem is and you can figure out the correct ForEach syntax.

Comment: that's what I'm trying!